# Eclipse Debugging is being executed or not

Tags: eclipse

During debugging an Application , 
Assume taht a line of execution is taking a lot of time , how can we know that Eclipse  still in the process of  Debugging ??

For example assume that the method client.submitOrder() shown below is taking 5 mins to get executed ??
Is there any Indication shown anywhere that eclipse is still running that method ??

```
public void test()
  {
  try
  {

ServiceResponse response = client.submitOrder(request);
System.out.println("Doen")
}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have started the application in Debug mode and if you are in the Debug View, the thread executing the method shows that the method it is in **Stepping** state.

I don't have a screenshot for this at the moment, but will try to upload one soon.